# AWS DynamoDB Queries Not Showing user data unless with Admin privileges

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm currently not able to query DynamoDB as a generic user to obtain the user's own details. It's worth noting when given admin privileges the user can execute queries and the work as intended; so it's not a problem with the data but rather the privileges of users.

I believe the problem is arising due to the nature of "owner" property in graphQL and my means of authentication (which is email & password). I believe the "owner" property might only work with username & password but I cannot find any documentation to back this so it's a stab in the dark. Does anyone have any ideas as to why the user is unable to receive their own data?

Query:
[image: Query & Result]

Admin Privileges:
[image: Admin Privileges]

Schema.graphql:

```
type User @model 
@auth(rules: [
{allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] },
{allow: owner, ownerField: "username", operations: [read]}
])
{
  id: ID!
  email: String!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace ownerfield "username" with "id"

```
type User @model 
@auth(rules: [
{allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] },
{allow: owner, ownerField: "id", operations: [read]}
])
{
  id: ID!
  email: String!
}
```